# How to Remove zero after and before Decimal Using php

Tags: php

Below code works fine but in second variable name fixed_2 why it shows 3 digit after decimal? I tried many ways didn't get any hope.

```
$text = "000892021.2408000";

$fixed_1 = preg_replace('/000/','',$text);
$fixed_2 = preg_replace('/.000/','',$text);
$fixed_3 = preg_replace('/000./','',$text);

var_dump($fixed_1);
var_dump($fixed_2);
var_dump($fixed_3);
```

output

```
 string(11) "892021.2408" string(13) "000892021.240" string(13) "92021.2408000"
```

Any help please explain?

Comment: What are you trying to match? In regex `.` matches anything so `.000` matches *any character followed by 3 zeroes` so the regex matches `8000` and replaces it with an empty string.

Comment: since it seems to be a number, have you tried casting it to `float`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the regular expression you used for $fixed_2 is **".000"**. It means remove all strings that start with any character followed by 3 zeros. "." means any character, so it will match **"8000"** and will remove it. Thats why you got output of **"000892021.240"** in $fixed_2

Comment: Then what i need to use to remove 000 only?

Comment: The $fixed_1 variable seems to have the correct output

Comment: The output will like this 000892021.2408 i made it with nested trim function but want to show with this function.  any help pls?

Comment: Try: `preg_replace('/(\d\.\d+)000/','$1', $text);`. See the documentation on: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

you could use  a nested ltrim() rtrim()

```
    $res = ltrim(rtrim($text, '0'), '0');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the solution using nesting. I just wanted to remove the last zero after decimal not all so i made it. 
   ltrim(rtrim($text,"000"));
but why it showing 3 digit when use preg_replace?

Comment: Your last  regexp rules  mean  ..3 zeros  and each char  `000.` .. so you have 3 last 0